# How can I restore this XML abiword document to a readible editable .doc (or otherwise)?

Tags: xml, abiword

I have recently started using Abiword on my ubuntu desktop. Libreoffice caused one of my word processing documents to crash. I have never had this issue with microsoft word but I mainly use ubuntu. So I decided to switch to abiword. I have been saving my word processing documents via abiword in the .doc format. However, recently when I came to open the file, all this XML code is being spit out. First I opened it with microsoft word. Then I thought maybe that was the issue, so I switched to abiword in ubuntu. It worked.....for about a day. Now all my work is in XML code.

The document begins with XML and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE abiword PUBLIC "-//ABISOURCE//DTD AWML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.abisource.com/awml.dtd">
<abiword template="false" xmlns:ct="http://www.abisource.com/changetracking.dtd" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xid-max="46" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" fileformat="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:awml="http://www.abisource.com/awml.dtd" xmlns="http://www.abisource.com/awml.dtd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="3.0.0" xml:space="preserve" props="dom-dir:ltr; document-footnote-restart-section:0; document-endnote-type:numeric; document-endnote-place-enddoc:1; document-endnote-initial:1; lang:en-US; document-endnote-restart-section:0; document-footnote-restart-page:0; document-footnote-type:numeric; document-footnote-initial:1; document-endnote-place-endsection:0">
<!-- ======================================================================== -->
<!-- This file is an AbiWord document. -->
<!-- AbiWord is a free, Open Source word processor. -->
<!-- More information about AbiWord is available at http://www.abisource.com/ -->
<!-- You should not edit this file by hand. -->
<!-- 

======================================================================== -->
```

How can I restore this into a normal document?

Also, why did this happen and how can I prevent this? I am considering just using word in Windows or using Google docs (though cloud word processing makes me paranoid because of 1) Privacy 2) If the internet cuts, I lose my work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. Copy the text of the whole entire document to a blank file with a .doc. Reopen in Abiword. It works. It destroyed a small amount of the data at the end. I have no idea where that data went. I am guessing perhaps RTF is a more stable format.

Comment: I don't know why this works, but it does - like you, I lost some of my data, but your method helped hasten the restoration process.

Comment: Wow, literally two years later (same day too!) and the answer to my own question helped someone.